# Новая библиотека в Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, mpi

[image: mpi.h не доступно]

Когда я пишу `#include<mpi.h>` Xcode видит эту библиотеку но при компиляции выдает ошибку! Как исправить?

Comment: Не может найти mpidefs.h, скорее всего не прописаны include пути к этому файлу.

Comment: А как добавить библиотеки в Xcode? Какои путь? 
А в терминале при компиляции выдает - 
dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopen-pal.20.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, разве нет?

Comment: Я хочу решить раз и навсегда эту проблему с MPI

Comment: проблему с MPI не решить...

Comment: Спасибо за такую помощь. Очень помогло.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440170/mac-xcode-6-4-header-include-path), там есть процесс добавления пользовательских путей в картинках.

Comment: Спасибо. Библиотеки добавил. Но что-то не узнает Xcode , наверное потому-что я добавил Windows.h.

Comment: Через терминал выдаёт - symbol not found:_ clock_gettime expected in :/use/lib/libSystem.B.dylib